# I've changed my login by manual editing the /etc/passwd and my former password is not recognised

Tags: login, password, password-recovery, etc, passwd

I've modified the /etc/passwd by changing manualy mickey to mike such as:

```
mike:x:1000:25357:mike:/home/mickey:/bin/bash
```

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to log as mike, my former password in not accepted.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password itself is stored in the file `/etc/shadow`.

Either you have to change back the username in the `/etc/passwd` or you also have to change the according username in `/etc/shadow`.

If the usernames in both files do not match then you will not be able to log in.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what I need to do. But my problem is that To edit the /etc/shadow I need to login as mickey. How can I solve that?

Comment: @Wraf Start from a CD with a life system and mount the HDD. Then you can edit the file `/etc/shadow`.